# Strange white area in panel c#

Tags: c#, image, gdi, picturebox

I have a problem with panel and weird area on it. I fill my panel with many `PictureBox`es 32x32px, and a small area of this panel is filled with white area.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

You can see that the first `PictureBox` has specified grass image, which is 32x32px, but the PictureBox below has only half of it's image. It's very strange.

I have also an `onClick` event specified for `PictureBox`es to change it's background to other image. If I click on 'working' `PictureBox` it's background changes, but when I click on 'corrupted' one, it doesn't.

So basically, my question is - what could be the reason for such effect? Is it possible to find it out without analysing a code? I would like to avoid putting a code here, because it's very complicated and long.

## EDIT

I used WinSpy++ and it is the result (red point is a place where i hover cursor)
so we can see that `PictureBox` is partly hidden behind this white area.

[image][image]

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? What happens if you put a breakpoint at the start of the `onClick` handler and click the icons?

Comment: @gt Yes, VS2012. When I set breakpoint and click on this corrupted `PictureBox`, it doesn't stop at this breakpoint, so the method isn't called. It's like those PictureBoxes don't exist or something.

Comment: In that case, perhaps when they are being created an exception is thrown. If not, then they may be being displayed elsewhere, or may not be visible.

Comment: @gt But as we see on his picture, some PictureBoxes are semi-working. Half of them is diplayed, and second half not.

Comment: Ok, try something else. It looks like a panel is superimposed on top of the boxes. Try using [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17) to examine the panels to ensure that they are where they are supposed to be.

Comment: I find it very stange that the pictureBoxes are "ahöf displayed" and the one to the right are like "90% displayed". I thin that sowmthing is in front of the pictureboxes. The picturebox in the top left corner is in front of that thing again.
Try to enumerate all the controls within your C# program that are not pictureboxes and list them with coordinates. You should find _something_ close to the top left corner.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster yes, that's strange, because I don't have any other components in my panel, only PictureBoxes. And also in WinSpy++ when I move my pointer over this white area it doesn't show anything. By the way, what does "ahöf displayed" mean? :):)

Comment: More ideas: Is it possible that the PictureBoxes are the wrong size? Perhaps force them to be the size you expect. Could it be related to Z-order (e.g. `Control.BringToFront` / `.SendToBack`)? Have you ensure that the images/controls are not being disposed somewhere?

Comment: That meant "half displayed" sorry ^^
Can you provide the .Designer.cs file? If you don't create the thing it might be in there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the question is still active, but I'll try to respond anyway. It is more a comment on it, but since I'm not allowed to make comments yet I'll just answer.

I had encountered a similar issue when implementing some `picutreBox` drawing using `onPaint` event handler. The problem was that I called `pictureBox.Invalidate()` during `onPaint` and it caused displaying of the unwanted white color box. You might want to avoid using `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` in your `onPaint` event if there is one.

If this is not the case it might also help to refresh the `form` or `pictureBox`es that are corrupted. Try to call `this.Refresh()` after the `form` initialization, preferably in `onLoad` or `onShown` event handler.

If it still doesn't help then the problem is somewhere else, I'd guess there is a control hidden somewhere that causes that. But we'll need to see some code in order to suggest any other advice.